# Unhandled exception at 0x001D6653 in Lid.exe: 0xc0000094: integer division by zero

Tags: fortran

I am trying to write the code for Lid-Driven Cavity in Fortran.

When I want to run the code, suddenly the `integer division by zero` errors appears.

I know what is the problem but I don't know how I can solve it. I even changed some numbers in order to avoid this issue but again happened.
I uploaded the photo of the error

[image: here]

I searched about it and there are some answers for C++ but I could not find anything for Fortran.

```
Program Lid
    
    implicit none
    Integer :: I,J,nx, ny, dx, dy, L, W, Iteration, Max_Iteration , Re, M, N, dt
    Real :: Delta
    Real, allocatable :: u(:,:), v(:,:), p(:,:), u_old(:,:), v_old(:,:), p_old(:,:), X(:), Y(:)
    !***************************************************!

    PRINT *, "ENTER THE DESIRED POINTS ..." 
    PRINT *, "... IN X DIRECTION:  SUGGESTED RANGE (20-200)" 
    READ*, M 
    PRINT *, "... IN Y DIRECTION:  SUGGESTED RANGE (10-100)" 
    READ*, N 
    
    ! Define Geometry
    dt = 0.001
    Delta = 2
    Re = 100
    L = 10
    W = 10
    dx = L /Real(M-1)
    dy = W /Real(N-1)
    
    ALLOCATE (X(M),Y(N),u(M,N),u_old(M,N),v(M,N),v_old(M,N),p(M,N),p_old(M,N))
    
    ! Grid Generation
    
    Do I = 1, M
        x(I) = (I-1)* dx
    End Do
    
    Do J=1 , N
        y(J) = (J-1) * dy
    End Do
     
    ! Boundray Condition
    Do I=1 , M
        u(I,1) = 0
        u(1,I) = 0
        u(M,I) = 0
        u(I,M) = 1       ! Lid Velocity
    End Do
    
    Do J=1, N
        v(J,1) = 0
        v(1,J) = 0
        v(J,N) = 0
        v(M,J) = 0
    End Do
    
    ! Initialization
    
    Do I=2, M-1
        Do J=2, N-1
            
            u(I,J) = 0
            v(I,J) = 0
            p(I,J) = 0
            
        End Do
        
    End Do
    
    ! Solver
        Do I=2, M-1
            Do J=2, N-1
                u_old(I,J) = u(I,J) 
                v_old(I,J) = v(I,J)
                p_old(I,J) = p(I,J)
            
                u(I,J) = - dt / 4* dx * (( u(I, J+1)+ u_old(I,J))**2 - (u_old(I, J)+u(I,J-1))**2) - dt / 4* dy * ((u_old(I,J)+ u(I-1,J)) &
                    * (v(I-1,J) + v(I-1, J+1)) - (u_old(I,J) + u(I+1,J)) * (v_old(I,J) + v(I,J+1))) - dt / dx *(p(I, J+1) - p(I,J)) &
                    + dt / Re * ((u(I+1,J) - 2 * u_old(I,J) + u(I-1,J)) / dx**2 + (u(I,J+1) - 2 * u_old(I,J) + u(I,J+1)) / dy**2) + u_old(I,J)
            
                v(I,J) = - dt / 4* dy * (( v(I-1, J)+ v(I-1,J+1))**2 - (v_old(I, J)+v(I,J+1))**2) - dt / 4* dx * ((u_old(I,J)+ u(I,J+1)) &
                    * (v(I,J+1) + v(I-1, J+1)) - (u_old(I,J) + u(I,J-1)) * (v_old(I,J) + v(I-1,J))) - dt / dy *(p(I, J+1) - p(I,J)) &
                    + dt / Re * ((v(I+1,J) - 2 * v_old(I,J) + v(I-1,J)) / dx**2 + (v(I,J+1) - 2 * v_old(I,J) + v(I,J+1)) / dy**2) + v_old(I,J)
            
                p(I,J) = - Delta * dt / 2 * ((u(I,J+1)+ u_old(I,J)) - (u_old(I,J) + u(I,J-1))) - Delta * dt / 2 &
                    * ((v(I-1,J)+ v(I-1,J+1)) - (v_old(I,J) + v(I,J+1)))
            
            End Do
        
        End Do
        
    
    !-----------------------OUTPUTS GENERATION----------------------------- 
OPEN (1,FILE='FIELD.PLT') 
WRITE (1,*) 'VARIABLES=X,Y,u,v,p' 
WRITE (1,*) 'ZONE I=',M,' J=',N 
DO J=1,N 
  DO I=1,M 
    WRITE (1,*) X(I),Y(J),u(I,J),v(I,J),p(I,J)
  END DO 
END DO 
    
End Program Lid
```

Comment: If you run it with  a debugger you could probably step through and narrow the problem down. Either it is a code error in comparison to theory or the theory is wrong or the input is wrong or division by 0 should be allowed and probably result in +/- infinity. Compiling flags can modify how to handle division by 0.

Comment: Here is some help if you use ifort http://www.jaist.ac.jp/iscenter-new/mpc/altix/altixdata/opt/intel/fc/10.0.026/doc/main_for/mergedProjects/fpops_for/fortran/fpops_fpew_f.htm

Comment: Thank you... That problem is solved...but there is another problem. when I run the code, exactly nothing happens and just says that " ... has exited with code 0 (0x0)..."..I didn't know that whether ask a new question or ask my question here

Comment: I believe that if M or N is greater than 10 you might end up with dx (integer) being 0. (I think my compiler would yell at me that dx is integer and a rounding is needed) Perhaps put in a check after dx or dy are calculated. It doesn't give meaning to not step forward...

Comment: Also i think closing the file would be a good thing before ending the progam. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/fortran/fortran_file_input_output.htm

Comment: I.e. `close(1)` right before `End Program Lid`

Comment: Thank you... Unfortunately I don't know what is the matter. Actually, I think it works but it runs so fast and does not give any result. I think there is a problem in the code but I cannot find it since it does not gives any error..!!!....

Comment: Is the file 'FIELD.PLT' not created?

Comment: it is created but when I want to open it with tecplot, it gives me an error....when I check the data of the file with Note-Pad, all of the data are zero...!!!... I am really confused...

Comment: Welcome. Please never insert error messages as pictures. Always copy and paste the error message as text. It is really important. Also, use tag [tag:fortran].

Comment: Thanks Vladimir for editing my post...

Comment: Please tell us what values you are using for M and N. My strong suspicion is that the comment by @ErikThysell holds the answer as to why your program is behaving incorrectly, but without M and N I can't say for sure.

Comment: Thank you so much.... Actually, I have just tested 3 different numbers for M and N. At first M and N =5.... Then M and N = 50.... then M and N = 100....for all of them the problem still exist...!!!

Comment: Which problem? Divide by zero? Or all of the data is zero? Or another problem? And is the problem the same in each case?

Comment: Divided by zero is solved (I introduced dx and dy as an "integer"at that time, when I changed them to the "Real" that problem solved... The problem that now I face is data equal to zero or in other word, software just send an empty output or something like that....since it build the output but it does not open with tecplot..it gaves me an error....when I open it with Note-Pad , there are many zero value...!!!

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand what you mean here - it would very much help if you were much more quantitative in describing what you are seeing. But I will say that what you have looks like a single sweep of a Jacobi or Gauss-Seidel solver. These normally need many, many sweeps to produce any sort of accuracy to the solution. And as you initialise to zero after just a single sweep many values will remain at zero - you need many more than 1 sweep to fill al the values in.

Comment: Thank you...I created an external loop and set it to 2,000 iterations. But the problem still exist.
The problem is that in the created results, the value of all variables at different times is considered zero...
In fact, the equations(U,V,P) do not seem to be solved at all...
But it does not give me an error message either

Comment: Please show the updated code - or better ask a new question showing the updated code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the yellow arrow shown on the image indicates the line (72) where the exception occurred:

Apparently `dx` is or becomes zero, because that's the only devision done on that line.

You must know what it means when `dx` is zero or what causes it, unless it's a programming or data input issue that causes it.

In any case you must make sure that you don't execute that part of your code that divides by zero.

What you need to do to prevent this, fully depends on what your code is supposed to do. I can't help you with that.